# Querying external domains using .Net through Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, active-directory

I am currently developing a script to help me with my job.  Basically what I need to do find a way to use .NET to perform some AD queries to an external domain.  Here is what the situation would be:

- Take laptop to external client
- Plug laptop into network (not joined to the domain)
- Run my program with account given by client to perform read access to an AD domain

Since my mastery in coding is currently only PowerShell, I am building the program around that.  To ensure backwards compatibility to PSOHv2 with no native admin tools on a system, I am leveraging the direct access to .NET that POSH has.  What I need help on at this point is perform a specific .NET function to gather data.  The code I have is this:

1. [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext]$asdf =
   New-Object
   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext('forest',
   'domain1.com', 'bob', '!@QWASZX12qwaszx')
2. [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.GlobalCatalog]::findall($asdf)

This code above will work on any machine that is joined to a domain.  It doesn't matter if the domain is external, brand new, trusted, etc...  I stood up a VM fresh out of the box and failed to run the code.  Promoted it to a DC in a brand new forest and it worked perfectly.  Demoted it and it failed again.  Below is the error that I receive:

Exception calling "FindAll" with "1" argument(s): "Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."
At line:1 char:128
+ ... ryContext]$(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Direc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryOperationException

My question is through .NET can I make POSH think I am apart of a domain?  Obviously there is a way to perform the query in .NET because I can do it once the machine joins a domain.  I think it might something to do with the security context in .NET but I am so new at .NET and C# that I'm in a little over my head.

I know there are native POSH commands in POSHv3 Win 8 and up that would make this so much easier, but I am trying to account for the least common denominator in the mass market (Win 7, POSHv2 in my opinion).   Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a VM image you could use to join to the domain? That way you can keep your host machine pristine, and subject just the VM to the required domain policies and related hassles.

Comment: I had that thought.  The other concern I had was if I wanted to hand the module over to the client in case they didn't want my machine physically connected to the network.  But I guess I don't need that .NET access then.

I think more over, this turned into a pride thing once I encountered this problem to solve it. LOL